# Where are the Android Gradle repository URLs defined?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

From the Android Studio build.gradle (Project) file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
}
```

I know that the "repositories"-block defines the repositories from which Gradle pulls the dependencies. But this aren't URLs.

So I wonder:
**Where are the precise sources defined? How does Android Studio know, were to get the resources from?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`google()` or `jcenter()` or `mavenCentral()` are shortcuts for the maven repos.
They are defined in the gradle code.

You can refer [this link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/constant-values.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.ArtifactRepositoryContainer.GOOGLE_URL):

```
public static final String  GOOGLE_URL  "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/"
public static final String  MAVEN_CENTRAL_URL   "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/"
```